# AngularJS directive: Produce different HTML depending on $scope variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I just started using AngularJS and immediately ran into a problem:

I have a sidebar which contains "*action-buttons*" - depending on the currently active view, different buttons should be visible.

My view-controller defines an object which looks as follows:

```
$scope.sidebar.actionButtons = [
            {   icon: "plus",  label: "Add",    enabled: true,  url: "customer.new" },
            {   icon: "minus", label: "Delete", enabled: false, action: function(){ alert("Not implemented yet"); }}
        ];
```

As you can see, there are two different kinds of action-buttons: Either the button changes to another view (`url` is set to `customer.new`), or the button triggers an arbitrary function (`action` is set to `alert()`).

Each button type has to generate some slightly different html, and I'm not able to get this working.

---

**After playing around for several hours, here is my current (not-working) approach:**

My sidebar uses the following template-code to generate the buttons:

```
<ul class="nav" id="sidebar-action-buttons">
    <action-button ng-repeat="button in actionButtons" button="button"/>
</ul>
```

Now, the `actionButton` directive has everything it needs and should produce the html depending on the button type:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('actionButton', function($compile) {
        function linker($scope, $element, $attrs){
            var innerHtml = '';
            $element.attr('ng-class', '{disabled: !button.enabled}');

            if($scope.button.url) {
                $element.attr('ui-sref-active', 'active')
                innerHtml = '<a ui-sref="{{button.url}}">';
            } else {
                innerHtml = '<a ng-click="button.action()">';
            }
            innerHtml += '{{button.label}}</a>';

            $element.html(innerHtml).show();
            $compile($element.contents())($scope);
        }

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: { button: "=" },
            link: linker,
            template: "<li></li>"
        }
    });
```

This generates the correct content. The problem here is, that the attributes which are placed on the `actionButton` element (in this case `ng-class='{disabled: !button.enabled}'`) are not compiled.

---

How can a directive produce different html depending on scope variables? What is the correct approach for doing this? How can I also compile the newly added attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time the ng-class is added to the action-button element, the digest is over with for that element.  You could call $scope.$apply(), but I would add the ng-class to each anchor element instead, then there would be no need to call $scope.$apply() again.

Comment: I can definitly add the `ng-class` in the sidebar-template. However, the `action-button` directive would not be self-contained anymore and I want to avoid that if possible. `$scope.$apply()` can't be called within the `link` function.

Comment: I'm using this solution for now, but there has to be a better alternative.

Comment: If you added ng-class in the inner html along with the ui-sref and ng-click, the directive would still be self-contained.

Comment: That's correct, but my html looks as follows: `<ul><li><a/></li>  ... </ul>`, where `li` is the action button. I want the ng-click to be applied to `<a>` and the ng-class to `<li>`.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I think you should just forget about the directive and have them all have ng-click to a function that then does an if statement, one does $state.go and the other calls that arbitrary function.  You would have to send the button object to the controller, but that's okay.

Comment: Haha, nice out-of-the-box thinking. That might be an ideal solution for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are compiling `content()` of the `li` but `ng-class` has been added with `li` itself. Simple solution is to add `ng-class` directly with the `action-button` directive i.e.

```
<action-button ng-repeat="button in actionButtons" button="button" ng-class="{disabled: !button.enabled}"  />
```

Comment: That's a possible solution (also recommended by cabey77), but as I mentioned in the comments there, the action-button directive would not be self-contained anymore and I want to avoid that if possible.